# Sql query for pattern matching on a keyword list with 2 character word

Tags: sql, teradata

I have a predefined list of keywords , which I want to attach to a text during pattern matching.

For e.g :

Suppose the list of my keywords is : ['DZ' , 'BL' , 'TS' , 'FZ']

The characters that I will be attaching one of these keywords is 'SN'

The text I am doing string matching in is : 'RMK A02 SLP 29861 FZSNB24E36'

I want to extract strings which have any one keyword from the list + 'SN'

Thanks in advance.Apologies for bad articulation. I am new to asking questions on Stack Overflow

Comment: Thanks @GordonLinoff. Will keep this in mind for future use. I basically want to run this code in Teradata, but an answer in SQL will also work for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can list the allowed values in the regular expression:

```
select regexp_substr(col, '(DZ|BL|TS|FZ)SN'
```